# How does getting field or method by name works in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and some things are not clear to me.
For instance, in C++ if we have

```
    class A {
        int field1;
        int field2;
        void method() { }
    } a;
```

and we use `a.field1` or `a.method()`, compiler already knows where they are stored in memory relatively to `a`. But Java has .class files which have the information about fields and methods with their names so that it doesn't matter where they are stored in memory for ones who use those fields and methods. Does it mean that when we do `a.field1` in Java, JVM first figures out where this field has to be in memory relatively to `a` and then gets this field or does it change all `a.field1` to `*(a + offset of field1)`, `a.field2` to `*(a + offset of field2)` etc on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation is essentially the same in Java as it is in C++: The JVM knows where the fields are within the object.

If you want all the gory details, you can read up on it in [the JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/), in particular the [`getfield` bytecode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.getfield), which says amongst other things:

> The *objectref*, which must be of type `reference`, is popped from the operand stack. The unsigned *indexbyte1* and *indexbyte2* are used to construct an index into the run-time constant pool of the current class (§2.6), where the value of the index is *(indexbyte1 << 8) | indexbyte2*. The run-time constant pool item at that index must be a symbolic reference to a field (§5.1), which gives the name and descriptor of the field as well as a symbolic reference to the class in which the field is to be found. The referenced field is resolved (§5.4.3.2). The value of the referenced field in objectref is fetched and pushed onto the operand stack.
>
> The type of *objectref* must not be an array type. If the field is `protected`, and it is a member of a superclass of the current class, and the field is not declared in the same run-time package (§5.3) as the current class, then the class of *objectref* must be either the current class or a subclass of the current class.

Comment: Does JVM calculate those indexbytes when the program starts and places them in all places where code uses fields or are they calculated during compile time?

Comment: @Artem: Compile-time, I'm pretty sure. If I compile a class then use `javap -c ClassName` to look at the bytecode, I see things like `getfield #6` and such.

Comment: and what happens if implementation of ClassName changes? Does it mean that I need to recompile all classes which rely on ClassName? (Maybe it would be interesting to check it myself, anyway, thank you for your answers)

Comment: The 'indexbyte' part might be a bit confusing. It is just used to make the .class file smaller by using a constant pool. The `indexbyte` refers to the constant pool of the .class file, and points at a 'String' representing the field name. That means that `getfield` only uses the field name to resolve the field, the actual field offset has nothing to do with `indexbyte`.

Comment: @Clashsoft: Thanks. How does it proceed once it has the string field name? (I'm not sure why Artem cares, but...)